# Comparing group medians in a binary variable

Tags: nonparametric, median

I have two samples of binary variables (i.e. 0 or 1). Both samples have unequal observations but the same median value of 0. When I test to see whether the two samples' median values are statistically different from each other, both the Wilcoxon rank-sum test and Moody's median test show a statistically significant p-value. How can both samples have the same median value yet the aforementioned tests show a statistical difference? Thank you.

**Full sample**

Group A: 0 x 1412, 1 x 693

Group B: 0 x 1345, 1 x 760

**Stats from Mood's median test**

T-stat: 4.58

Grand median: 0

Contingency table: array([[693, 760], [1412, 1345]])

[Link to Wilcoxon rank-sum test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ranksums.html)

[Link to Mood's median test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.median_test.html)

Comment: The rank-sum, at least, is not a test of equality of medians. It seems to be fairly accurately described at your link. From my reading of how it implements Mood's test, you should have no counts in either sample below the grand median, so it should not be giving significance (if it gives a p-value at all, it should be 1). Can you give a table of how many 0's and 1's you have in each sample and show the results you got?

Comment: I've edited my question with full sample details and Mood's test output.

Comment: I see the problem now. The default they have for Mood's median test is to count values *equal to* the median as *below* the median. That's why it's significant. (If they did what I'd regard as the sensible thing in this instance - ignore values equal to the median - then the table would be `[[693, 760], [0, 0]]` and you'd get a very different result.

Comment: I get the error message "ValueError: All values are above the grand median (1.0).". I think since we ignore values equal to the median (i.e. 0), both samples are only left with 1's. Therefore the t-stat for the null hypothesis is undefined.

Comment: You shouldn't get a t-statistic at all -- according to the information it should be a chi-square. Unless I missed something I guess. But yes, undefined is correct by what I would have done.